# List of tuples to Numpy recarray

Tags: python, numpy

Given a list of tuples, where each tuple represents a row in a table, e.g.

```
tab = [('a',1),('b',2)]
```

Is there an easy way to convert this to a record array? I tried

```
np.recarray(tab,dtype=[('name',str),('value',int)])
```

which doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
np.rec.fromrecords(tab)

rec.array([('a', 1), ('b', 2)], 
          dtype=[('f0', '|S1'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```